# Laravel 9 and Jetstream with Inertia/Fortify added username login works, but username is not treated as case sensitive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, inertiajs, laravel-fortify

I've successfully added a user field to Jetstream / Inertia registration and logins in Laravel 9 with Fortify. The users can now login using either email, or username.

After searching through [Laravel validators](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation), looking through a couple vids like Povilas Korop's YouTube video "[Laravel Jetstream: Login with Email, Name or Phone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRJ2RuiLVGQ)", and reading [official Fortify documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify), I've not found a way to make the user name case sensitive. Regardless of version stored in DB and what user enters, 'Admin' can login as 'admin', vice versa, or even as 'ADMIN'.

I suspect I need to add something to the `Fortify::authenticateUsing` method in `app/Providers/JetstreamServiceProvider.php`, somewhere in this section:

```
        Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->username)
            ->orWhere('username', $request->username)
            ->first();

        if ($user &&
            Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return $user;
        }
```

Looking for someone to point me in the right direction to make username case sensitive. Full code in the form of a commit in which I added username logins is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/eclectic-bytech/webcourses-ngx-v4/commit/2f16e5431654e818db6eaa7513372bbc80fc731c#diff-e4ebae0ade119905fb222b0ac6ac2b5e7fe539e4b8f8aacff374c3e6c3ad474d).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had found this solution early on, and that it works, yet I am concerned about a couple of things before accepting this is the way to go.

Currently, the username field has the same collation as the password field. Is it due to hashing, that it can get away a _ci collation, and I shouldn't compare these two?

I'm also concerned about sorting anomalies one day in the future, when I've forgotten the user field has a unique collation. I'm willing to accept that this is the price to achieve CS usernames, and want to clear these items before implementing it.

Comment: On closer review, I think I'll go with the suggested collation change. One of the things I've learned about development is that when unsure, go with the solution that is easiest to undo or replace... this collation fits that mantra perfectly. Thank you!